# Why the following line runs before await completes?

Tags: node.js

below is my code. In the code, I am trying to make a query to a table. But the problem is even after using await the following console after the await function is getting printed first then the callback function is being called. What is the solution to make the callback call first then the following console will be called?

```
 async getUsers() {
        let sql = 'SELECT * FROM login';     
        let query = await this.db.query(sql, (err, result)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
                    this.res = JSON.stringify(result);
                    console.log(this.res); //calls second
        });
        console.log(this.res); // calls first

     return this.res;
}
```

Comment: Does `db.query` return a promise?

Comment: What db library is this? It probably doesn't return a `Promise` for you to `await` if you provide a callback.  Additionally, don't provide a callback, you are defeating the purpose of `await`.

Comment: it's mysql . I am really new to node js. so I am asking you a question as I don't have solid knowledge about async-await . So promise is necessary for await to work. right ?

Comment: also can you help me how can i solve this issue ? i want to return value as the result of the query .  How can I pause the execution until the query gets executed completely with result?

Comment: Which **exact** mysql library, [there are multiple](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mysql).

Comment: `await` ONLY works with promises.  My guess is that `this.db.query()` does NOT return a promise when you pass it a callback.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have made some solution using mysql2. async getUsers() {
            try{
                const [rows,fields] = await this.db.execute(sql);
                console.log(rows);
                this.res = rows;
            }catch (e) {
                console.log('caught exception!', e);
            }
         return this.res;
    } but now the problem is 'TypeError: this.db.execute is not a function' if I made connection in constructor . But if i make connection in this function it works . what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [Node MySQL 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2), the syntax should be as follows based on the documentation here: [Promise wrappers](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Promise-Wrapper.md).

The thing to understand is that `Promise`s are intended to make callbacks unnecessary.  In turn, `async/await` is intended to make `Promise`s easier to follow.

```js
async getUsers() {
  try {
    const result = await this.db.query('SELECT * FROM login');
    this.res = JSON.stringify(result);
    return this.res;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that your `catch` handler does not propagate errors so the caller of `getUsers()` would not know there was an error and the resolved value of the promise `getUsers()` returns would be `undefined` if there was an error because you have no return value in the `catch` block.  If you're not going to actually do something in the `catch`, then you probably want to just let the rejected promise propagate upwards to the caller (e.g. remove the `catch()` block).

Comment: I tried this but encourted another issue stated 'TypeError: this.db.execute is not a function'. I made the connection in constructor. what is the problem right now ?